# Вывод содержимого списка в окно

Tags: javascript

Вывод содержимого элемента списка в окно `alert` по щелчку мыши не работает! Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка. Пример кода:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function (){
    var li_elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for(var i=0; i< li_elements.length; i++)
    {
    li_elements[i].onclick = function()
    {
      alert(li_elements[i].innerHTML);
    }
    }
    }();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <ul>
        <li>Первый</li>
        <li>Второй</li>
        <li>Третий</li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(li_elements[i].innerHTML);
```

В контексте функции ни li_elements, ни i не определены. Делайте так:

```
alert(this.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

На момент запуска скрипта `<li>` не созданы, так что перенестите вас скрипт перед `</body>`